# Create laravel model from SQL View

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, model

anybody....

i've a question about laravel and sql.

can we create a model from sql view?

i have a sql view, and using it into my laravel. i want make model with name like this MyViewName, so if i want to use it, i just call with :

```
$query = \MyViewName::where(....)->get();
```

anyone can show me how to do this?

Comment: you can use sql view model in eloquent just like as a table

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of most SQL servers a view is treated like a table (on the surface at least), and you can interact with a view in many of the same ways you can if it were a table.

With this in mind, creating a model with any ORM would be done the same way that you would a table, just set the table name to be that of the view.